# Cannot redefine sections style with titlesec

Tags: sectioning, titlesec, section-titles

I've been asked to use a given format for a paper and I have to use the following format for sections:

[image]

being size of the paragraph text 10pt and that of the section 11pt. I also have to reduce, respect to that of LaTeX, the spacing between the paragraph and the section title and change the enumeration to roman numbers.
I have tried to make it with titleformat command but I could not reach the desired style. I hope you can help me! Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Could you show your (failed) attempts so far? This would help in answering the question. Preferably you should provide a small complete document, including documentclass, usepackage statements, and one example section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the information you provide, this is what I can answer

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\makesc}[1]{\textsc{#1}}

\newlength{\mylength}
\setlength{\mylength}{\the\parindent}

\titleformat{\section}[hang]
  {\fontsize{11}{13}\selectfont}
  {\makebox[\mylength][l]{\Roman{section}.}}
  {0pt}
  {\makesc}
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{\baselineskip}{.3\baselineskip}

\begin{document}
 
 \section{Lorem Ipsum}
 \lipsum[1]

 \section{Lorem Ipsum}
 \lipsum[1]
 
\end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]

Comment: You're a genius! Thank you